# Customize the position of group in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

Is it possible to customize the position of groups in a `UITableViewController`? For example, drawing the groups horizontally or customize the space inside two groups.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: not clear, what means "drawing groups horizontally" at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are targeting iOS 6+, [`UICollectionView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) implements the features you are looking for.  It can do a horizontal layout out of the box and `UICollectionViewLayout` allows you to customize everything about the display and positioning of items.  If targeting iOS 4.3+, there is a third-party implementation of it called [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView).

> The `UICollectionView` class manages an ordered collection of data items and presents them using customizable layouts. Collection views provide the same general function as table views except that a collection view is able to support more than just single-column layouts. Collection views support customizable layouts that can be used to implement multi-column grids, tiled layouts, circular layouts, and many more. You can even change the layout of a collection view dynamically if you want.